# Cross-Domain API Access Security

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cors, jsonp

This is a question about cross-domain API security.  The best way to ask this so it could be useful for others is through a hypothetical example.

- Domain APIHOST.COM wishes to allow access to its resources to FRIENDLYSITE1.COM and FRIENDLYSITE2.COM (but no other domains)
- The FRIENDLYSITEs are owned by others, and APIHOST has no direct server access to them.  They may be running any server technology.  They are willing to host additional content, but nothing too complicated.

When Bob visits FRIENDLYSITE1.COM using his web browser, his credentials for FRIENDLYSITE1.COM (or APIHOST.COM) are irrelevant.  Security should be handled between APIHOST.COM and FRIENDLYSITE1.COM.

I have looked into all of the cross-domain request technologies (CORS, iFrames, JSONP), but all of them assume that the security should come from Bob the browser, and not from the FRIENDLYSITE1.COM domain that Bob is visiting.

Is there a way to do cross-domain API access where the security is handled between the two servers, without involving Bob and his browser?

Comment: Are you trying to allow access to APIHOST.COM from Javascript in web pages hosted by FRIENDLYSITE1.COM or are you trying to allow access to APIHOST.COM when API calls are made directly from FRIENDLYSITE1.COM's web server?  There is a big difference here.  In one case, the connection is originating in the user's browser from a particular web page.  In the other case, the connection is originating from the secure environment of a server.

Comment: Ideally, there would be no need for FRIENDLYSITE to update anything on their server.

However, it should be FRIENDLYSITE's credentials that are used to verify the security of the API call.

Comment: What credentials are those from FRIENDLYSITE?  There are no "automatic" credentials sent with every web request from FRIENDLYSITE.  You cannot reliably authenticate the origin of a web request.  You need actual secret credentials sent with a request in order to authenticate the request.  You could do reverse DNS to try to figure out if a request is coming from an IP address owned by FRIENDLYSITE, but that is far from perfect form a security point of view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure communication between two servers, then you are going to need to use a secure transport (like https) and use some credentials that are only provided to sites that you wish to allow access.

Those credentials can be as simple as a username and password if you want.  In that case, you would provide FRIENDLYSITE1.COM some credentials and whenever it wants to make a connection to APIHOST.COM, it will include those credentials with each API request (or perhaps your API supports a login that creates a cookie that can then be used for subsequent API calls).

---

If, on the other hand, what you really mean by your question is that there are web pages hosted by FRIENDLYSITE1.COM that contain Javascript in them and that Javascript in those web pages wants to access APIHOST.COM, then that is a different situation.  Since this situation is actually connected from the browser on the user's computer (an insecure environment), you using credentials like in the previous example exposes those credentials to anyone and thus they are no longer secret.

About the best you can do in this case is to enable APIHOST.COM for CORS and only allow sites FRIENDLYSITE1.COM and FRIENDLYSITE2.COM for CORs access.  This will keep any web pages from any other sites from accessing APIHOST.COM from a browser, but it will not prevent any server or any server proxy from accessing APIHOST.COM.  It's basically impossible to allow access from a specific web page, but not from anywhere else.  This is because web pages are completely insecure so you can't use credentials from a web page, but keep them secret.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I agree that a server-to-server connection would be ideal, but that won't be a realistic real-world scenario.

Bob visits FRIENDLYSITE.com with his browser, and FRIENDLYSITE needs to make an API call to a third-party server to get Bob what he needs, but the third-party server only needs to verify that the request is from FRIENDLYSITE... not every Bob should need to login to complete the request.

(I hope that makes sense)

Comment: @ZackAustin - do you understand that when Bob visits FRIENDLYSITE and Javascript in the FRIENDLYSITE web page makes an API call to your site that the API call is coming from Bob's browser, NOT from FRIENDLYSITE?  You can use CORS on your API server to enable your API to be used only from FRIENDLYSITE's web pages (when accessed from a browser). CORS does not prevent non-browsers from accessing your API.  You would have to use credentials for that.